# how to setup a deferred on a callback, using jquery?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, promise, jquery-deferred

for some reason i can't seem to setup a deferred. Here s my setup

```
// some class
find: function () {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    Func.run(function (err, results) {
        return results;
    });

    deferred.resolve(results);

    return deferred.promise;
},
test: function () {
    $.when(this.find()).done(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

im trying to call `this.find()` but i want it to return a promise... the issue is that `Func.run()` is async, so i need to wait until that is finished as well.

I'm also using `backbone.js`, is there is a different way to do it there.

any ideas what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Your deferred object never resolved. Put your resolve statement inside `Func.run`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your resolve statement inside your `Func.run`:

```
find: function () {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    clearTimeout(this.timer);
    this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
        return Func.run(function (err, results) {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        });
    }, 1500);

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Comment: it did worked. the returns needs to be `return deferred.promise();`